# sequelize dialectoptions , UTC and dates, for mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am still learning how to use sequelize. 
I am using sequelize 5 along with node 10 and mysql2 .

I am setting my connection like so

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: dbs,
  username: usr,
  host: hst,
  password: pwd,
  port: prt,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  dialectOptions: {
      useUTC: true,
      dateFirst: 1
  },
  define:{
      timestamps:false,
      paranoid:false,
      freezeTableName: true
  }
});
```

and I am getting the following warnings

> Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: useUTC.
>   This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an
>   error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a
>   Connection
>
> Ignoring invalid configuration option passed to Connection: dateFirst.
>   This is currently a warning, but in future versions of MySQL2, an
>   error will be thrown if you pass an invalid configuration option to a
>   Connection

If I remove the `useUTC: true` and `dateFirst: 1` from the `dialectOptions`, the errors obviously go away.

What am I missing and how can I set those options for `mysql`

Comment: With Sequelize 5, I think you can only use these options https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options when dialect is `mysql`. See also https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6317